# Chaining click events to perform the same action

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have a table containing a list of documents---when you click on a checkbox next to that document a copy of it appears in a separate div (a "Favorites List", if you will).

I created a custom context menu and I want one of its options to do the exact same thing as the above.

I tried to chain the onClick event for the context menu to the original part that clicks on the checkboxes, but nothing happens when I attempt to click on "Add to Favorites" in the context menu.

Any thoughts?

#### JS snippet:

```
function faveFunc(evt) {
  const $table = $("#km-table-id")

  let table = $table.DataTable();
  let favesArr = [];

  let data = table.row(this.parentNode).data(),
  checked = $(this).is(":checked"),
  dataIndex = favesArr.indexOf(data);
  if (checked) {
    if (dataIndex === -1) {
      favesArr.push(data); // add item
    }
  } else {
    if (dataIndex > -1) {
      favesArr.splice(dataIndex, 1); // remove item
    }
  }  


  // - Appending selected faves to div - //

  ($(".populate-faves").empty()); // removes all previous entries
  for (var i = 0; i < favesArr.length; i++) {
    $(".populate-faves").append(JSON.stringify(favesArr[i].Titles) + '<br/><br/>').addClass("faved-doc");  
  }


}; // ------------ faveFunc

$("#km-table-id.checkbox-class, [data-action='add']").on("click", faveFunc)


  console.log(faveFunc)
```

#### HTML:

```
<ul class="custom-menu">
  <li data-action="open">Open Document</li>
  <li id="add-id" data-action="add">Set As Favorite</li>
  <li data-action="email"><a href="mailto:?subject=subject">Email Document</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you know which TR to operate on, it should be as easy as `table.row(this.parentNode).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click')`

Comment: Since I attached `[data-action='add']` to the `on("click")` at the end I figured that it would work the same as the previous class selector did.

Comment: But the Event object delivered to your handler will have a different structure associated with the event. The Event target for instance will be the LI while the other appears to be an HTMLInputElement (checkbox) that is in a different location in the DOM.

Comment: (slaps forehead) I see what you mean. I separated `.checkbox-class` and `#add-id` into two separate `on('click')` lines and changed the checkbox one to `$(".checkbox-class").on`...it's working again. I'll fiddle around with the context menu selector to see what's up.